# Calling the right guard in middleware for Multi-auth system

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-middleware, custom-authentication, laravel-guard

I am adding a custom authentication system via guards , models and providers.

After trying to read some documentation and articles, I am bit confused about the different way of invoking guards and middleware

Question 1:
So, if I want to invoke (default) authentication in a particular route (as defined in auth.php as "default => [ 'guard' => 'web' ... , is it
`'middleware' => ['auth']]`
Does this mean the default auth ? Or the middleware "auth" - which is included in the Kernel.php as below

`protected $routeMiddleware = [`
`'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,`

if i want the default auth as defined in "web" of config/auth.php
should it be
`'middleware' => ['auth']]`  or
`'middleware' => ['web']]` or
`'middleware' => ['auth:web']]`

Question 2:
Now there is a middleware group called "web" which has useful things like StartSession, EncryptCookies, CSRF Protection, - so if I have a custom guard "abcguard" - is session management, cookie encryption done through some mechanism or I should explicitly add that middleware "web" in my routes /route-group?

Question 3:
what if I have a custom guard called "abcguard" defined in auth.php as such
and I have a middleware group called abcguard (just for illustration purpose) -- how do I make sure that that a route dashboard is available after the abcguard authentication and passing though middleware abcguard

Is this the right way?
`'middleware' => ['auth:abcguard', abcguard]]`

How does Laravel know which one is authentication and which one is just a middleware? Or is "guard" just a name for another middleware - the only specific behaviour is that a guard determines how users are authenticated and a middleware might just check if an user is authenticated?

Q4 - In the statement below, how does laravel find out which abcguard is a guard and which is a middlewar group?
`'middleware' => ['auth:abcguard', abcguard]]`

Answer (score 2):

1. First, you seem to confuse `web` middleware group (defined in Kernel) with `web` guard (authentication mechanism using session) for auth middleware, and they are even not related TBH. Guard is used to authenticate users, and middleware group just holds different middlewares for your web routes. If in your `auth.php` config, you have default guard `web`, the `'middleware' => 'auth'` will end up using `web` guard. In case you want to use other guard, you will need to use `'middleware' => 'auth:other_guard'`
2. Again, `web` middleware group only holds middlewares for ALL of your web routes. You should not add `auth` to all of them, for sure.
3. The right way will be `'middleware' => ['auth:abcguard', 'abcguard']`, yea. In this case, you have `auth` middleware using `abcguard` guard and `abcguard` middleware group.
4. When you write `auth:abcguard` you are calling `auth` middleware and passing `abcguard` as argument to it's handle function. Same if it was `web` - default session guard, or `api` - default auth token, or `sanctum` - sanctum's session cookie. Middleware groups are defined in your `App\Http\Kernel::class`. In case you have `abcguard` middleware group there, you will be using all middlewares defined in that group.

Comment: So for #4, If I want to use my own defined "abcguard" guard from auth.php and my defined "abcguard" middleware group from Kernel.php from my route what is the right syntax for a route group? Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:abcguard','abcguard]], ..... ?

Comment: yes, that's right

Comment: So for a Route group, I want to use the "auth" middleware from the Kernel.php what is the syntax --> Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']],,,,? How does laravel know I am trying to invoke the middleware "auth" from Kernel.php and not the "web" auth from auth.php ?

Comment: So from the official documentation -- https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication#protecting-routes --- I see to protect my routes, I should do this ---> Route::get('/flights', function () {
    // Only authenticated users may access this route...
})->middleware('auth'); --- my question is which "auth" is this -- the "auth" defined in Kernel.php routeMiddleware = [''auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class, ]... or the default web auth in config/auth.php

Comment: `auth` middleware registered in your Kernel as well in `$routeMiddleware` array. It's basically binds class descriptor to `auth` keyword, that's all. Default guard for `auth` middleware is set on `auth.php` config. In case you are not passing any guard as argument, you will use default guard.

Comment: Yes, you get it all right

Comment: What will be the middleware name for admin guard if one is using sanctum for authenticating SPA ? 1) 'middleware' => 'auth:sanctum,admin' -> this doesn't work user tries to access admin routes. 2) 'middleware' => ['auth:sanctum', 'auth:admin'] -> but this works when user tries to access admin routes, so is second one best practice to follow ?